# What built-in functions have bad time/space complexity and their alternatives?

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, built-in-symbols

It's surprising that `Join` is $\mathcal{O}(n)$ (due to copy) while I've been using it as a convenient way to join lists together. It also reminds me of suggestions about `ls~AppendTo~x` and `ls=Flatten@{ls,x}` ...

Are there other built-in functions in *Mathematica* that are actually inefficient and should be used less? If any, what are their alternatives?